# iOS: How to update a UILabel from UITableView in same ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a view controller with a UITableView on the left half, and two labels on the right (kind of like the setting app on an iPad). The idea is that when the user selects a cell from the table, the labels on the right hand side will update according to the following code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *audience = [_arrayForDMAudience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *message = [_arrayForDMMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _audienceLabel.text = audience;
    _messageLabel.text = message;
    [_audienceLabel sizeToFit];
    [_messageLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

The NSStrings for the labels are being correctly displayed ONLY when the user presses on the same cell a second time. I believe the issue is to do with the sizeToFit calls, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

The first time they select it, only the first line of text that will sit in the 450px wide label shows, and the second touch causes the rest of the lines to appear. This happens for all cells 100% of the time.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: As far as I remember, for sizeToFit to work properly, numberOfLines property of the label needs to be defined.

Comment: [yourtableview reloaddata];

Comment: @harsh.prasad the issue with defining the number of lines is that the text then becomes centred in the middle of the label, rather than beginning at the top left... Currently the number of lines is set to 0 (unlimited) as the amount of text that may need to be shown can differ immensely, could this be an issue?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the labels that need updating aren't actually located in any part of the table view, rather off to the side of the table view within a normal view controller

Comment: u used in the label in any method

Comment: @JaidenPatel maybe its got to do something with baselines. Check this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment

Comment: Also, can you post some screesnshots of the problem. It would be better to understand that way.